# Pagination widget changing forward slashes to '%2F' in URL

Tags: php, url, yii2

I'm following the official yii2 docs, in which we have a [tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-databases.html) that shows how to interact with the database using pagination. Everything works fine, except that when I used the pagination widget to go to next page, the URL changes from `index.php?r=country/index` to `index.php?r=country%2Findex&page=2`. This is confusing me: what's causing this conversion from `/` to `%2F` and why? Further, if I edit the URL to `index.php?r=country/index&page=2`, there's no change in the behavior.

Perhaps this has more to do with browsers/servers (mine is Apache2 on Ubuntu), but I can't tell. Would someone be good enough to explain?

Comment: [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#page-12). `/` is a reserved URI character and should be percent encoded in query strings.

Comment: @4ae1e1 So Yii2 is changing the query string according to the 'standard' but is flexible enough to allow them when typed by user? If so, I wonder why the official docs are built around using `/` to separate controllers and actions in the query string.

Comment: I don't know what yii2 is and I don't know php well. But I know `/` shouldn't appear in query strings. (I was in the triage queue.)

Comment: Can you post your url configuration from web.php file in config folder

Comment: @NuriddinRashidov Can't find any URL configuration there. Here's the full web.php file: http://pastebin.com/Cf0R2sQK

Comment: Okey add this urlmanager rule in your components array :   'urlManager'=>array(
      'urlFormat'=>'path',
      'showScriptName'=>false,
), And test it pls reply is it work  or not

Comment: Got an Exception: `Setting unknown property: yii\web\UrlManager::urlFormat`. Indeed, there's no `urlFormat` property in the `UrlManager`: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html

Comment: It seems you add array into  wrong place. Pls Refer this for more info about urlmanager http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/url-manager-in-yiiframework-2-0/

Comment: @NuriddinRashidov Even in the link you've provided (and I'm not sure why you'd prefer it over the official docs), there is no property called `urlFormat`.  Try searching for it. Did you mean something else?

Comment: Yeah u right, i was wrong with UrlFormat i was old version config. instaed of this u can use this  'enablePrettyUrl' => true,

Comment: @NuriddinRashidov Now this is the error I'm getting http://oi67.tinypic.com/2ld7gwm.jpg and my controllers have stopped working. Why are we discussing pretty URLs anyway? I don't want pretty URLs; I want to know why the conversion is happening.

Comment: I'm sorry. I faced up to this problem before and I solved this switching url rules to friendly url.

Comment: Maybe you set false to $pagination->pageSizeParam = false;. Pls reply if not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want pretty URLs, then you can at least turn off the script name:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => false,
    'showScriptName' => false,
```

In the `components` section of your config.

That error you got when you turned pretty URLs on is because you haven't configured Apache properly.

There must be a .htaccess present in your web directory and Apache must have `Override all` in the site config.

[Yii2 Guide on Pretty URLs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#using-pretty-urls)

[Yii2 Installation guide for Apache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#recommended-apache-configuration)

Edit:
This is the url that a new Yii2 application gives me for the site index action:

```
http://yiipository.dev/index.php?r=site%2Findex
```

That is just how Apache - and internet in general I guess - works.

So the answer is that it is not the pagination widget that does unspeakable things to your URLs. :)

EDIT
This should probably do it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Enable URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine On

    # Strip unwanted query strings from the url
    # RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^?]*)\? 
    # RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]

    # comment the next line out if you get trouble
    # RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index\.php\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I am not an expert in Apache - how can you ever be? :p

Comment: Brilliant explanation! Any idea how I can fix that or do I need to dive into the horror known as Apache documentation? :D

Comment: I added a .htaccess example to the answer :)

Comment: Thanks, to I take it that pretty URLs are the only way out. Although I have neither the knowledge not the energy to explore that route for now, I'll accept this as the answer as you did help me unshroud the mystery.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean your link or decode the `%2F` by using

```
rawurldecode('index.php?r=country%2Findex&page=2');
```

this will output to `index.php?r=country/index&page=2`